# Changing Windows options from code

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to change some windows optins from c# code.
For options like the powersetting that was easy (I used PowerCFG and the appropriate GUIDs), but I have alot more settings I want to change, which are not that easy to find on the internet:

`System->Notifications and Actions->Deactivate all notifications
System->Notifications and Actions->Symbols for the taskbar: Only Network
System->Notifications and Actions->Systemsymbols: Only Clock and Network

System->Offlinemaps->automatical update: off

Privacy->Background apps->deactivate everything
Privacy->Feedback and Diagnosis->Amount: Never`

....and a lot more. Those are a few examples and while I would be glad if someone could post their solution if they already solved those problems, I would prefer an indicator on where to find that information myself.

Context:
I will have to set up a few 100 computers with a new windows 10 and I want to avoid setting them all manually.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Group Policy, not custom hand-written code that goes against the end user's intentions. There's a reason more and more setttings aren't accessible to programs at all and must be set through the sacntioned interfaces: it's open to abuse.

Comment: So, if i want to set up 100 computers with a new windows 10 and have the same settings everywhere.....I will have to set them manually?

Comment: No, that's what administrative templates/sysprep/cloning software are for. Configure it once, roll out globally. Running a program manually on those 100 computers would still be way more trouble than necessary. From that angle this is more of an IT question than a programming question; you could try [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) instead.